# How could I line feeds with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How could I line feeds with Google Apps Script? I have used "\n","
","\r", but all of them couldn't realize line feeds. e.g.:

```
function submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var strMessage = "";
  if (e.parameter.Eventtitle == "")
  {
    strMessage = "Event title mustn't be null!";
  }

  if (e.parameter.Fromdate == "")
  {
    strMessage = strMessage + "\n" + "<br>" + "From date mustn't be null!";
  }

  if (e.parameter.Where == "")
  {
    strMessage = strMessage  + "%s\n" + "Where mustn't be null!";
  }

  if (e.parameter.Description == "")
  {
    strMessage = strMessage + "\r\n" + "Description mustn't be null!";
  }

  if (strMessage != "")
  {
    var messageLabel = app.getElementById("message").setText(strMessage);
    messageLabel.setVisible(true);
    return app;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `messageLabel` is a Label. Use a HTML widget instead of a Label and use `<br>` for line breaks.

Comment: See the documentation for HTML https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/html

Comment: createHTML I know, but createHTML will open a new Chrome window. I need write above messages on the current window. How could I do?

Comment: Have you actually tried it ? If not, please do. I think you have got it mixed up between a HTML widget and HtmlService.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another question. with createHTML method I could write message, but how could I remove the html message?

Comment: Just set it to blank string. 
PS: Please accept the answer if it has answered your question